# OO PHP MySQL connection

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm new to the PHP language and, in fact, started studying it this week.

While trying to connect some files to an SQL database, I get the following error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION in /home/cpapalardo/wwwroot/Calendario/Calendar.php on line 56

Line 56 would be:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT event_id, event_title FROM event");
```

I don't know what I did wrong. Could someone help me with this one, please?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
<?php include("DB_Connect.php");

class Calendar1 extends DB_Connect{

private $data;
private $month;
private $year;
private $daysMonth;
private $startDay;

public function __construct($dbo=NULL, $data=NULL){
    parent::__construct();

    if(isset($data)){
        $this->data = $data;
    }else{
        $this->data = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');              
    }

    //convert to timestamp and determines month and year of the calendar
    $ts = strtotime($this->data);
    $this->month= date("m", $ts);
    $this->year= date('Y', $ts);            

    //how many days the month has
    $this->daysMonth= date('t', strtotime($year.'-'.($month-1).'-01'));

    //what day of the week the month starts in
    $ts = mktime(0, 0, 0, $this->month, 1, $this->year);
    $this->startDay= date('w', $ts);
}

private function loadEventData($id=NULL){
    $sql = "SELECT 
                'event_id', 'event_title', 'event_desc', 'event_start', 'event_end' 
            FROM 'events'";

    if(!empty($id)){
        $sql .="WHERE 'event_id'=:id LIMIT 1";//returns one result
    }else{
        $start_ts = mktime(0, 0, 0, $this->month, 1, $this->year);
        $end_ts = mktime(23, 59, 59, $this->month+ 1, 0, $this->year);
        $start_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start_ts);
        $end_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $end_ts);

        $sql = "WHERE 'event_start'
                BETWEEN '$start_date'
                AND '$end_date'
                ORDER BY 'event_start'";
    }

}
}

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysql_query("SELECT event_id, event_title FROM event");
//fetch tha data from the database
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "ID:".$row['event_id']." Name:".$row['event_title'];

}

?>



<?php

class DB_Connect{
    protected $cn;

    public function __construct(){
        $cn = mysql_connect("testDatabase", "admin", "pass123");
        mysql_select_db("admin", $cn);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: The braces in your first body of code don't seem to match up, not in my IDE anyway. Try deleting the last brace after your last `while` loop, then moving it above `//execute the SQL query and return records`

Comment: Please look at MySQLi instead of MySQL functions for PHP.

Comment: You also have an opening comment tag `/*` in `/*$evento = mysql_query("select * from event");` but no closing `*/` so that will also throw/cause an error. It's hard to put in an answer (*which I might*), since I don't know if you want it commented out or not.

Comment: You are closing your method prematurely, right before the line which gives the error. And you are not closing your class. You should post the actual code.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. I did some changes on the code. I'm using notepad++, so I got a little confused with the braces. Sorry about the  inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

You are using single quotes for your columns and table. Either delete them or use backticks.

```
$sql = "SELECT 
        'event_id', 'event_title', 'event_desc', 'event_start', 'event_end' 
    FROM 'events'";
```

Should be:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
            event_id, event_title, event_desc, event_start, event_end 
        FROM events";
```

This line `$sql .="WHERE 'event_id'=:id LIMIT 1";//returns one result` using `:id` that's a binding method which is not implemented in your code.

You may have to change it to `$sql .="WHERE event_id=$id LIMIT 1";//returns one result`

without the quotes around `event_id` since it's a column.

**New rewrite:**

```
<?php include("DB_Connect.php");

class Calendar1 extends DB_Connect{

private $data;
private $month;
private $year;
private $daysMonth;
private $startDay;

public function __construct($dbo=NULL, $data=NULL){
    parent::__construct();

    if(isset($data)){
        $this->data = $data;
    }else{
        $this->data = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');              
    }

    //convert to timestamp and determines month and year of the calendar
    $ts = strtotime($this->data);
    $this->month= date("m", $ts);
    $this->year= date('Y', $ts);            

    //how many days the month has
    $this->daysMonth= date('t', strtotime($year.'-'.($month-1).'-01'));

    //what day of the week the month starts in
    $ts = mktime(0, 0, 0, $this->month, 1, $this->year);
    $this->startDay= date('w', $ts);
}

private function loadEventData($id=NULL){
    $sql = "SELECT 
                event_id, event_title, event_desc, event_start, event_end 
            FROM events";

    if(!empty($id)){
        $sql .="WHERE event_id=$id LIMIT 1";//returns one result
    }else{
        $start_ts = mktime(0, 0, 0, $this->month, 1, $this->year);
        $end_ts = mktime(23, 59, 59, $this->month+ 1, 0, $this->year);
        $start_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start_ts);
        $end_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $end_ts);

        $sql = "WHERE 'event_start'
                BETWEEN '$start_date'
                AND '$end_date'
                ORDER BY event_start";
    }

}
}

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysql_query("SELECT event_id, event_title FROM events");
//fetch tha data from the database
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "ID:".$row['event_id']." Name:".$row['event_title'];

}

?>



<?php

class DB_Connect{
    protected $cn;

    public function __construct(){
        $cn = mysql_connect("testDatabase", "admin", "pass123");
        mysql_select_db("admin", $cn);
    }
}
?>
```

---

### Original answer

The braces in your first body of code don't seem to match up, not in my IDE anyway.

Try deleting the last brace after your last `while` loop, then moving it above
`//execute the SQL query and return records`

I have modified it below for you to try.

Now, this line:

`/*$evento = mysql_query("select * from event");`

is hard to say if you want it commented out or not and will cause an error.

If so, either delete `/*` or modify to `/*$evento = mysql_query("select * from event"); */`

I also used/incorporated `mesutozer's` answer concerning this line (*credit to*)

```
echo "ID:".$row{'event_id'}." Name:".$row{'event_title'};
```

to be changed to:

```
echo "ID:".$row['event_id']." Name:".$row['event_title'];
```

This line `ORDER BY 'event_start'` should not be wrapped in single quotes.

Use

```
ORDER BY event_start
```

or

```
ORDER BY `event_start`
```

Rewrite:

```
<?php
include("DB_Connect.php");

class Calendar extends DB_Connect{

    private $data;
    private $month;
    private $year;
    private $daysMonth;
    private $startDay;

    public function __construct($dbo=NULL, $data=NULL){
        parent::__construct();

        if(isset($data)){
            $this->data = $data;
        }else{
            $this->data = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');              
        }

        //convert to timestamp and determines month and year of the calendar
        $ts = strtotime($this->data);
        $this->month= date("m", $ts);
        $this->year= date('Y', $ts);            

        //how many days the month has
        $this->daysMonth= date('t', strtotime($year.'-'.($month-1).'-01'));

        //what day of the week the month starts in
        $ts = mktime(0, 0, 0, $this->month, 1, $this->year);
        $this->startDay= date('w', $ts);
    }

    private function loadEventData($id=NULL){
        $sql = "SELECT 
                    'event_id', 'event_title', 'event_desc', 'event_start', 'event_end' 
                FROM 'events'";

        if(!empty($id)){
            $sql .="WHERE 'event_id'=:id LIMIT 1";//returns one result
        }else{
            $start_ts = mktime(0, 0, 0, $this->month, 1, $this->year);
            $end_ts = mktime(23, 59, 59, $this->month+ 1, 0, $this->year);
            $start_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start_ts);
            $end_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $end_ts);

            $sql = "WHERE 'event_start'
                    BETWEEN '$start_date'
                    AND '$end_date'
                    ORDER BY `event_start`";
        }

    }
    
}

    //execute the SQL query and return records
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT event_id, event_title FROM event");
    //fetch tha data from the database
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    
    echo "ID:".$row['event_id']." Name:".$row['event_title'];

    }

    $evento = mysql_query("select * from event");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($evento)){
        echo $row['event_id'] . "<br>" . $row['event_title'] . "<br>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Fred -ii-, thank you for all your help! I was in a hurry when I wrote this question and forgot to fix some part of the code. I still get the same error message, but now I can see the select results of MySQL! 

I'm still looking it up on how to fix this error message. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @CPpa You're welcome. I was just about to change `ORDER BY 'event_start'` to `ORDER BY event_start` which should not be wrapped in single quotes. See if that change will fix your code. I have edited my answer with the same code.

Comment: I spotted more errors. @CPpa if your posted code is your production code, let me know. I will be posting a quick edit.

Comment: See my **Edit** and under **New rewrite** @CPpa

Comment: I spotted something else. You have a query with `events` for your table and `event` in singular form; which one is it, or are you using both with two different tables? @CPpa

Comment: This line too `$sql .="WHERE 'event_id'=:id LIMIT 1";//returns one result` using `:id` that's a binding method which is not implemented in your code. @CPpa You may have to change it to `$sql .="WHERE event_id=$id LIMIT 1";//returns one result` removing the quotes in `event_id` since it's a column.

Comment: Everything seems fine with the code now. :)

Another message popped up, but I think it has to do with permission instead of code.

    Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /home/cpapalardo/wwwroot/Calendario/Calendar.php on line 56

I'm making some searches on this one.

Thank you very much for all your help! And sorry for the aweful code you had to go through!

Comment: You're welcome. If you feel that my answer solved it (or 99% of it), then let's close it by checking the White tick (gray outline) till it turns green. @CPpa

Answer (score 1):

You can access array elements with [] brackets, not with {}. You need to change following line:

```
echo "ID:".$row{'event_id'}." Name:".$row{'event_title'};
```

into following:

```
echo "ID:".$row['event_id']." Name:".$row['event_title'];
```

Comment: there are more not just it, no query will execute the code is written as `SELECT 
                    'event_id',` ... etc

Comment: You are right @AbhikChakraborty, I missed that while trying to reply quickly